# How to get value of the static variable of the java class in karate feature file directly

Tags: karate

I have a java class which is having all the required Urls for the application. I want to access this in feature file. I know it can be accessed by creating a get method.

```
 * def Config = Java.type('App.Config')
 * def stageEndPoint = Config.getStageEndPoint()
```

is it possible to get directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use this existing Java class in the `karate-config.js` so that it becomes a little easier in your feature files. For example:

```
function() {
  var Config = Java.type('App.Config');
  return {
    stageEndPoint: Config.getStageEndPoint(),
    someOtherEndPoint: Config.getSomeOtherEndPoint()
  };
}
```

Then in your feature:

```
* url stageEndPoint
```

(edit): well, even this was not enough apparently, so here's another idea:

```
function() {
  return {
    Config: Java.type('App.Config')
  };
}
```

And then:

```
* url Config.getStageEndPoint()
```

Comment: This is good. However I am trying to skip creating extra get method to access a variable.  I want to access it directly. Like -  var url = Config.stgEndPoint ;

Comment: @virendrachaudhary well, I edited by answer with one more option. how does that sound ?

Comment: Looks like I am still not clear enough. My point is not to create extra method to get value of the any static variable. It is not about getting single variable . We have many classes which have final static variable. We know that getter method is not required in java. It is directly accessed like App.stageEndPoint . I am looking for similar solution in karate as well.

Comment: If you had your config class as a normal Java bean you can certainly do `Config.stageEndPoint` but since it is all static variables, good luck trying to find a solution for this. My honest opinion is that you are being very lazy here. If you really have "many classes" that are your config, there's something wrong with your design. All the best :P

Comment: I have to write getter method now :) . Thank you Peter for prompt response.

Comment: great. note that you can use the `new` keyword in Java if needed. actually take a look at the `karate-config.js` for the Karate mock-servlet example, it will give you some ideas, look at the end of this page: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-mock-servlet

Answer (score 1):

You can write a karate-config.js file which has the URL's as given below

```
function() {

  return {
        baseUrl: 'http://192.168.0.199'
  }

}
```

and you can use this URL in your tests as follows

```
Background: 
    * url baseUrl
```